# return address of an item in vector using range based loop

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm trying to get addresses of vector items like below:

```
std::transform(m_vector.begin(), m_vector.end(), 
               m_address.begin(), 
               [](std::vector<T> val){return val.data();};
```

But it returns same address for all item. I think its the address of local variable vals` address.
How can I return address of item in vector without using raw for loop?
Thanks!

Comment: You probably wanted to take lambda parameter by const reference: `[](const std::vector<T>& val){return val.data();}`. As of now, you copy the vector and save address of that temporary vector in `m_address`. And you missed one `)` to end `std::transform(`, but I assume it's a typo.

Comment: Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: @lubgr it constains another vector

Comment: @yksisarvinen I'm tryin it now

Comment: You are right @Yksisarvinen. Its working. If you submit it as aswer I'll accept it correct answer. It think this would be fair because you replied it before eerorika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think its the address of local variable vals` address.

That's exactly correct. (Although to be more specific, it is the address of the internal buffer of the local vector).

> How can I return address of item in vector

You can have the argument refer to another object (in this case, the object inside the vector) if you declare the argument to be a reference:

```
[](std::vector<T>& val)
```